# How to call function overloaded by function which return partail function

Tags: scala, overloading, partialfunction

How to print "I'm not partial" using one of below `f` functions, and why below code is printing "I'm partial"? And maybe there are some general rules connected with functions (maybe with arity 0) which produced partial functions and name overloading in scala?

```
object T1 extends App{    
  case class C()
  def f: PartialFunction[C, Unit] = { case c:C ⇒ println( "I'm partial") }
  def f(c: C): Unit = { println("I'm not partial") }
  (f:C ⇒ Unit)(C()) // Why this is printing "I'm partial"?
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else going on-- any implicit conversions or anything that might not be obvious?  I just did a quick mock-up of your code, but I got the expected "I'm not partial" output.  Any other info you might be able to provide might be helpful.

Comment: Well, I got `"I'm partial"` also here, even substituting `C` by `Int`, for example. Interestingly, if you put both `f`s inside another method, the compiler complains about `f` being defined twice.

Comment: Yes, local overloading is not allowed. That gets me during innocent refactors.

Comment: None of `f` are functions. Both are methods. The first of these happen to *return* a function.

Comment: For a second, I thought a partail was some exciting FP thing I hadn't encountered yet. Partail recursion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression is not an application. Compare the definition of x with the ambiguous invocation:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object T1 extends App{    
  case class C()
  def f: PartialFunction[C, Unit] = { case c:C ⇒ println( "I'm partial") }
  def f(c: C): Unit = { println("I'm not partial") }
  (f:C ⇒ Unit)(C()) // Why this is printing "I'm partial"?
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object T1

scala> T1 main null
I'm partial

scala> import T1._
import T1._

scala> val x: C => Unit = f
x: T1.C => Unit = <function1>

scala> f(C())
<console>:12: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method f in object T1 of type (c: T1.C)Unit
and  method f in object T1 of type => PartialFunction[T1.C,Unit]
match argument types (T1.C)
              f(C())
              ^

scala> x(C())
I'm partial
```

[The spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution) says `f` is as specific as `f(...)` (bullet 3) but not conversely (by bullet 1).

The parens of an application means you're comparing two things that look like `f(...)`.

In case this helps, the usual way to prioritize:

```
scala> trait Helper { def f: PartialFunction[C, Unit] = { case c:C ⇒ println( "I'm partial") } }
defined trait Helper

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object T extends Helper {
def f(c: C): Unit = { println("I'm not partial") }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object T

scala> T f new C
I'm not partial
```

There are other API that you can write but not invoke in the normal way:

```
scala> trait X { def f(i: => Int) = i }
defined trait X

scala> trait Y { def f(i: Int) = 2 * i }
defined trait Y

scala> class Z extends X with Y
defined class Z

scala> new Z().f(42)
res5: Int = 84

scala> typeOf[Z].members filter (_.name.toString == "f")
res7: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(method f, method f)

scala> (new Z(): X).f(42)
res8: Int = 42
```

Or, no way to invoke the other function here:

```
scala> class YY extends Y { def f(i: => Int) = i }
defined class YY

scala> new YY().f(42)
<console>:20: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method f in class YY of type (i: => Int)Int
and  method f in trait Y of type (i: Int)Int
match argument types (Int)
              new YY().f(42)
                       ^

scala> (new YY(): Y).f(42)
res15: Int = 84
```

Comment: Btw, any idea of how to call the non-partial `f` directly in the original code? Or it isn't possible at all?

Comment: It's not possible because you can't require a "method type"; the arrow is allowed only at the definition site, so you can't `(f: => A => B)`. Other techniques are to add a param, or change the result type, since Scala will select an overload based on result type. Means to avoid overloading in the first place include magnet pattern.